# How to determine the host address of a server using Node/Express

Tags: node.js, server

Right now I am using Localhost and port is 5000 so my host and port is like
localhost:5000 how do i get it programatically instead of hardcoding.When the application is hosted on live server it will have the different address Localhost won't be available.I have tried os.hostname() but it gives me dev06 instead of localhost

Comment: Do you mean how does the server know its own address? Or how the client knows the server address?

Comment: How does Server know its own address...

Comment: Try out "public-ip" npm package

Comment: What are you trying to do with the IP address?  Your server already knows it's own port (when you started the server) and you can call yourself with `127.0.0.1:xxx`.   The actual IP address of your server may be different from your public IP address due to the hosting provider's network setup.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am trying to store an image to a folder where i have hardcoded the path like localhost:portnumber/folder/filename.What i am thinking is localhost won't be available when the application is hosted live

Comment: You don't need to store the server address in the path. The client knows the server address and the server knows the path from the root.

Comment: Although... if you did for some reason need to make a database of public addresses of the images rather than serving them back to the client, you may be best to tell the server what address to use, since you probably *don't* want an IP address in that case, and the alternative, which is doing a reverse DNS lookup, is tricky to make work in my experience.